# check if a variable is in array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

I have all my IPs in an array as below.

```
list_of_ips = Socket.ip_address_list.select{|intf| intf.ipv4?}
```

I am trying to use Enumerable **include** to check whether this array contains IP 192.168.1.27 which it does, but I get the return value as false.

```
puts list_of_ips[1].ip_address  ## This prints 192.168.1.27
puts $this_is_my_ip             ## This prints 192.168.1.27

puts list_of_ips.include? '192.168.1.27'  ## Gives me false
```

I think I need to use to filter the array with **ip_address** somehow, but not sure how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list_of_ips.any? {|ip| ip.ip_address == '192.168.1.27'}
```

Comment: Clever... Anything left ? :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to transform the objects in the array temporarily to strings to compare them to strings. Try this:

```
list_of_ips.map {|addr| addr.ip_address}.include? '192.168.1.27'
```

Comment: Yes.. it is... Voted up.

Comment: `list_of_ips.map(&:ip_address)`

Comment: @max: I always forget that shortcut, even though I've worked with ruby for years. Thanks!